# Controller no work

Tags: controller, cakephp-3.0

Routes:

```
$routes->connect('/textos',['controller' => 'Administracion', 'action' => 'textos']);
```

Controller:

```
class AdministracionController extends AppController {
  public function textos() {
    $this->set('textos', $this->Textos->find('all'));
  }
}
```

The Model ---> TextosTable

> Error: Call to a member function find() on boolean File
>   /srv/www/cake-arbol/src/Controller/AdministracionController.php Line:
>   20

Line 20: `$this->set('textos', $this->Textos->find('all'));`

What the problem? the name table is Textos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with line `$this->Textos->find('all')`

You have to load model Textos before using it,

```
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

class AdministracionController extends AppController {
  public function textos() {
    $textos = TableRegistry::get('Textos');
    $this->set('textos', $textos->find('all'));
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Ved Thank you!!